# How to select rows by substring? Similar to Google Suggest

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First of all, I have a database in which I store people's data. Then, there's a PHP page whose function is to search that database and retrieve suggestions while I type. So far, I'm using this:

```
$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE people.name = $name");
```

But the problem is, it only shows the suggestion when I type the full name that's stored in the DB. How can I make it search for a substring inside the name column, retrieving all people with that substring in their names?

Comment: 1. this doesn't work. 2. You are preparing it in vain.

Comment: Actually, I was using bindValue but I chose not to write it here as it would get too long. And I finally got it binding `"%".$name."%"` to the `:name` variable. But thanks for trying to help me anyway :)

Comment: I also used the LIKE operator.